# How is Bucky resurrected after death?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier, captain-america-the-first-avenger

In *Captain America: The First Avenger*, Bucky dies before coming back as The Winter Soldier in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.

Why was he chosen to become The Winter Soldier and how was he resurrected after his death?